# Linear or Non-Linear Model

Tags: statistics, regression

I have the following regression equation
\begin{align*}
y_i = \alpha + \gamma\cdot\beta\cdot x_i+ \varepsilon_i,
\end{align*}
where $y_i$, $x_i$ and $\varepsilon_i$ are $n\times 1$ vectors, $\varepsilon_i\stackrel{iid}{\sim}\text{N}(0,\sigma^2)$ for all $i=1,\ldots,n$ and $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$ are unkown constants.

Is this a linear regression model in the unkown parameters $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename $\beta \cdot \gamma = \delta$ and you have a regression in $\alpha$ and $\delta$ with $\epsilon_i$ denoting the model error.

Comment: So what kind of assumptions do I need in order to identify $\beta$ and $\gamma$ after this representation?

Comment: @dsforecast i don't understand why you need them separately - whoever modeled these separately likely wrote down conditions allowing you to determine these once $\delta$ has been found from the linear regression. Generally, you take $\beta \equiv 1$ to avoid the problem, but you have a specific problem here and it's details must be used.

Comment: ok, so the regression is not linear because of the interaction between $\beta$ and $\gamma$. Thanks.

Comment: yes, $\beta \cdot \gamma$ is **not** a linear relationship